# Error Passing ListItemCollection via ObjectDataSource to Custom Adapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, webforms, objectdatasource

I have an `ObjectDataSource` declared like this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="PaymentsDataSource"
                      runat="server"
                      DataObjectTypeName="Payment"
                      TypeName="PaymentAdapter"
                      SelectMethod="GetPayments">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="StartDate"
                              PropertyName="Text"
                              Name="startDate"
                              Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="EndDate"
                              PropertyName="Text"
                              Name="endDate"
                              Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LocationCodes"
                              PropertyName="Items"
                              Name="selectedLocationCodes"
                              Type="Object" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The control is question is `LocationCodes` declared like this:

```
<select id="LocationCodes"
        disabled="disabled"
        runat="server"
        class="chzn-container"
        multiple=""
        data-placeholder="Choose a Location Code(s)"
        style="width: 100%;"
        data-class="span10">
</select>
```

The server-side `Select` method on the adapter is defined like this:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
public List<Payment> GetPayments(
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate,
    object selectedLocationCodes)
{
}
```

Now, ***even though the `ListItemCollection` is successfully passed into the `Select` method and the code in the `Select` method can process without error***, the following error is still being thrown passively in `Application_Error`. Is there a way to ignore this error?

```
11/15/2012 13:37:49 168 (Machine=, App=34a846f1, Project=null, Dept=null, Thread=007, TraceLevel=1)
    Exception Source: mscorlib
    Exception Type: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
    Exception Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the way I solved this was by turning `ViewState` off on the `ObjectDataSource` element by adding this `ViewStateMode="Disabled"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot serialize an Object. If you were to change 
"***object selectedLocationCodes***" to some kind of predefined class then there should be no problem. 
In order for an object to be serialized it basically needs to be broken down into XML and that means it needs to know what type of data each field is. Object is not specific enough description because it can be anything.